# Get server name and scheme in freemarker with Spring MVC?

Tags: spring-mvc, freemarker

I'm using Freemarker as my view technology for a Spring MVC application. I need to find the server name and scheme and nothing I try seems to work. In JSP, there is an implicit `request` object that would have this info, but Freemarker doesn't seem to have an equivalent. I am exposing the Spring `requestContext` as `rc`, but `rc.request` is null.

Here is my view resolver config:

```
<bean id="freemarkerViewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerViewResolver">
    <property name="cache" value="false" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".ftl" />
    <property name="order" value="1" />
    <property name="exposeRequestAttributes" value="true" />
    <property name="requestContextAttribute" value="rc" />
    <property name="exposeSpringMacroHelpers" value="true" />
</bean>


<bean id="freemarkerConfig"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerConfigurer">
    <property name="templateLoaderPaths">
        <list>
            <value>${freemarker.templatePath}</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
</bean>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can't access the Request via `rc.request` because `RequestContext#getRequest` is protected, i.e. not accessible from FreeMarker/reflection.

Disclaimer: I'm no Spring-MVC expert at all, so the following approach might be completely insane, but it should work!

You can expose the raw request with a custom `FreeMarkerView` and `FreeMarkerViewResolver`, e.g.

```
public class CustomFreeMarkerView extends FreeMarkerView {
    protected SimpleHash buildTemplateModel(Map<String, Object> model, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        SimpleHash fmModel = super.buildTemplateModel(model, request, response);
        fmModel.put("RawRequest", request);
        return fmModel;
    }
}

public class CustomFreeMarkerViewResolver extends AbstractTemplateViewResolver {
    public CustomFreeMarkerViewResolver() {
        setViewClass(requiredViewClass());
    }   
    @Override
    protected Class requiredViewClass() {
        return CustomFreeMarkerView.class;
    } 
}
```

Then in your `freemarkerViewResolver` bean config you can use your custom view resolver class and access the raw request in your template via `${RawRequest}`, e.g.

```
Scheme: ${RawRequest.scheme}
Server Name: ${RawRequest.serverName}
```

This approach worked for me with Spring Framework 3.0.5.

Comment: Hm, that should work. I supposed I could throw in `response` and `session` for completeness. I'm just wondering why it doesn't do this already?

Comment: Spring-MVC already exposes the request to the template, but wrapped as a FreeMarker HttpRequestHashModel, which only provides access to servlet request attributes, but not request properties like serverName or scheme.